# I need to pass a user input from one activity to another in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So I tried the intent method but I always get a red underline under the "putExtra"

here is the code I tried:

```
next.setOnClickListener {
  var i=Intent(this,Screen6::class.java)
  i.putExtra("ID", id)
}
```

How can I do that?

EDIT:
the id needed the function to.toString() but now I need to get it from the other activity how is that possible

Comment: what error does android studio show ? have you tried to research that error a bit more to see what you can find ?

Comment: maybe `id` is not parcelable.

Comment: what do u mean by praceable

Comment: `i.putExtra("ID", id)` the "id" at the end did you assign it to something such as `String id` etc?

Comment: You might need to read more about android programming, Parcelable is quite a basic concept, this is a good introduction: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html

Comment: I need it in kotlin not java

Comment: If you're trying to figure out how to use the framework in the first place (e.g. to learn what parcelization is) I don't think the choice of language in the article is incredibly important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the intents to send data and parameters from one activity to another activity in kotlin

```
val intent = Intent(this@OneActivity,TwoActivity::class.java);
intent.putExtra("username", userName)
startActivity(intent);
```

Where "username" will be key and userName will be actual data you will pass.

Comment: how to receive it in the other activity ?

Comment: In the other activity, you use the below code
Fragment
` val ty = activity?.intent
        ty?.getStringExtra("username")`

for Activity
` val ty = intent
        ty?.getStringExtra("username")`
from my code am passing a String value that's why I used double "" and also received it with the getString method, you can also work with other data Type

Comment: you can also check out this link for more clarification

(https://devofandroid.blogspot.com/2018/03/pass-data-between-activities-using.html)